# Same name for all appendices

Tags: numbering, appendices

I have a problem with Appendices. I include them all in one big file. Here I include chapters and after including chapters, I include appendices as follows:

```
\begin{appendices}
\include{appendixA}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\include{appendixB}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\include{appendixC}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\end{appendices}
```

at the beginning of a file `appendixA` I have:

```
\appendix
\chapter{Computation of thickness}
\label{sec:ComputationOfThickness}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Computation of thickness}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Appendix:}{}}
bla bla bla
at the beginning of file appendixB I have:
\appendix
\chapter{Computation of surface tension of glass}
\label{sec:ComputationOfSurfaceTensionOfGlass}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Computation of surface tension of glass}
bla bla bla
```

the problem is that in the whole file, all appendices are labeled as A and not A, B and C.

Could you tell me, where I have a mistake? The numbering is working very well for all chapter I have in the previous text, but once I change into appendices it stops and all is numbered as A.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using the `appendices` environment (of **memoir** class or of the **appendix** package), no `\appendix` command is required.

Without the environment, only *one* `\appendix` command must be issued.